# cuando lo abro una pagina desde chrome movil salen un monton de links en la cabecera

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome-app

Tengo un problema con mi sitio web. Cuando lo abro desde chrome movil salen un monton de links en la cabecera (adjunto imagen). El sitio lo cree sobre wordpres (php, mysql) y el tema lo diseñe yo mismo.

ya he probado navegar desde el escritorio y con otro navegado movil (opera movil) pero en estos se ve bien la pagina. No se como ver tampoco el codigo fuente de la pagina que se carga en el movil. Lo prove en un moto g4 play pero tambien otras personas me comentaron les cargo la misma pagina en otros dispositivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ahora vas a tener que aclarar la pregunta porque si no va a volver a ser cerraad como que no esta clara. necesitamos ver el codigo, ejemplos y todo para poder reproducir esto. Si no, estas esperando que hagamos magia.. lee [ask] para más info.

Comment: Ya adjunte la imagen que me sale en el navegador. No se que codigo mostrar es una pagina en wordpres y un tema que yo cree. En el movil no se como ver codigo fuente de la pagina y en los navegadores de escritorio no sale eso. Y nuevamente que pena como dije antes es la primera vez que hago una consulta en este medio generalmente encuentro las respuestas antes de formularlas :)